# rails string limit does not prevent too long strings from being inserted in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote a migration for a Rails 4 project to add a character limit to a string column. I used the following code:

```
change_column :articles, :name, :string, :limit => 40
```

The migration with `rake db:migrate` went fine, resulting in the following line in `db/schema.rb`:

```
t.string   "name",  limit: 40,  null: false
```

But when I enter a string with more than 40 characters in the form (generated by a scaffold), there isn't any error message and the too long string is inserted in the database.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I would just add a validation in your articles model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the RDBMS you're using, the field limit won't be validated at the database level. To ensure you're getting great error messages when your constraints are being violated, use ActiveRecord validations.

Try:
`validates_length_of :name, maximum: 40`

In your model class.

Comment: I'm using SQLite3. So then I shouldn't have made a migration for this ? It's against the [Rails philosophy](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html): "Don't Repeat Yourself". Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It's a good habit to make your migrations as robust as possible as you did here. Sure you're only using SQLite for now, but if you decide to take your app to production, you'll probably want to switch to a more comprehensive RDBMS that will support limit constraints and etc. This is for the sake of your datastore's integrity. In my mind ActiveRecord validations aren't for data integrity, they're more for creating user friendly error messages for when your data constraints are violated. I agree it doesn't feel DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), but it's necessary replication for a variety of reasons.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3, sqlite does not enforce limit and column types. it is dynamically typed